# The Nav Items are looking like a link

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Here is the code: I copied the bootstrap CND from getbootstrap.com. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Company Name</a>
      </div>

      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-dark">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-dark">Item 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

I've been stuck in this for a while now. Double checked the mdn docs and some tutorial videos in Youtube, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-decoration-none` to the class of all your links.

It will look like:

```
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Company Name</a>
      </div>

      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-decoration-none nav-dark">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link text-decoration-none nav-dark">Item 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

if you want to change colors of the link through Bootstrap class, see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/colors/), or just customize them in your custom CSS file.